# Not able to compare two Lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to Compare two `List` types based on its column values `Id` and `Name`. `List1` has `names` and `ids` and `List2` also contains `Id` ,`Name` and other columns. Now I want to check a condition that one input Name receive in a method. That Name is not exist in `List2` but It may exist in `List1`.The condition should validate that `List1 Id` does not exist in `List2 Id` and the external Name might exist in List1. I have used below query for achieve this.

```
var IsNameExists= db.List1.Where(a => List2.Any(b=>b.Id!=a.Id) && a.Name== InputName).ToList();
```

When I am using this query, I am getting exception like

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'ProjectName.DBEntities.List2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

I am not sure what i have done wrong on my query. Please guide me how can I achieve this to check the Name existence on List1.

Corrected query and Answer is:

```
var IsNameExists= db.List1.ToList().Where(a => !(List2.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(a.Id) && a.Name== InputName).ToList();
```

Comment: `List2.Any`? Shouldn't it be `db.List2.Any`?

Comment: `List2.ToList().Any(b=>b.Id!=a.Id)`

Comment: I have added an answer which is same as your question (just a minor correction)

Comment: so what your new code is doing it sucking all the data back for that table into memory, yes this will work on small tables, however if you have a large table this will be incredibly slow and very inefficient. though if you are aware of this, all good :)

Comment: You can answer your own question if you like, if that has solved your problem suitably

Comment: @TheGeneral: I used your logic and update a small change .Got the correct query. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this i guess, basically its just selecting out the ids and sending them to SQL as primitives to make a nice simple sql query

The fundamental problem here is trying to mix whats in memory with LinqToSql which in essence tries to convert you statement to a query and runs it on the database. The database wont know about your List that you have memory, so the solve is either give it something it understands or do it in memory. The following example extracts the ids out, and gives the data base something it does know, a list of int

```
var ids = List2.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var IsNameExists= db.List1.Where(a => !ids.Contains(a.Id) && a.Name== InputName)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, It is working fine using your logic. Is there anyway that can we do these two lines code into single line of query?

Comment: Nope. When we are using with single query It is giving the same exception.

Comment: Convert `List2 ids` to `Hashset<int>` for more efficient processing, else its O(N^2) right now

Comment: @TheGeneral can you review, my answer ?

Comment: @TheGeneral :  I have added the ToList but that is also giving the same exception.

Comment: @SuryaKavitha yeah sorry i think i have been giving you a steer in the wrong direction, and its still trying to convert your in memory list to sql. however the original answer should work

Comment: @TheGeneral : I have made small change and now it is working. I have updated the query like  db.List1.ToList().Where(a => List2.Any(b=>b.Id!=a.Id) && a.Name== InputName).ToList()

Comment: @SuryaKavitha so what this is doing it sucking all the data back for that table into memory, yes this will work on small tables, however if you have a large table this will be incredibly slow and very inefficient and a bit smelly, i think you shouldnt worry about putting things on one line, there are more important things to worry about :)

Comment: @TheGeneral, I have edited my post and updated the answer on top of  using your logic.